# fullpage.js and wordpress nav

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, nav, fullpage.js

I am trying to implement fullpage.js in my WordPress theme. Everything works fine, but I cant find a way to use the standard WordPress nav with the fullpage.js anchors.

this is how i get my pages:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=5' ); ?>
<?php if( $query->have_posts() ): ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>    
<div class="section" id="section0">
     <div class="content">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="content-text">
                    <h1 class="headline-about"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That's my header including nav.

```
    <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>"><img id="logo-main" class="img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/birnis-logo.png"></a></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                   <?php
                      wp_nav_menu( array(
                      'theme_location' => 'top_menu',
                      'depth' => 0,
                      'container' => false,
                      'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                      'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
                      //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                      'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                      );
                    ?>
              </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
   </nav>
</header>
```

and here I load fullpage.js

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            verticalCentered: false,
            anchors: XXX,
            menu: '.nav'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is there a way to change the code, so that every time I add a page to my menu it automatically adds a new anchor?

For example I create a new section with a different page_id.
After that I add the page to my menu in the WordPress back end.
Now I want the new list item to scroll to the right section.

I hope you understand what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks for your time, your answer is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any element in your markup with the class "nav".
It seems you have to use `nav` instead of `.nav` in the `menu` option:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        verticalCentered: false,
        anchors: XXX,
        menu: 'nav'
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i changed the code but it didnt help. 
I guess i have to add something here:
anchors:['firstPage', 'secondPage'],

Comment: Well, I though you knew that already... the anchor option should contain an array as detailed din the docs, or otherwise, just omit it.